# Adding subViews on non-main Thread not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I create a UIView contentView and display it. I then fetch data from server and create a bunch of subviews displaying the data. I am using MBProgressHUD to display while waiting on data.

```
if (datasetSubBar.panels == nil) {
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:datasetSubBar.filterListView animated:YES];

    HUD.labelText = @"Creating Panels";

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [datasetSubBar createPanels];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:datasetSubBar.filterListView animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

in `createPanels` method, i fetch the data then create the panels. The panel is created, added to filterListView (the content view) and then add the constraints:

```
for (int i = 0; i < panels.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    DatasetFilterListPanelView *panel = [panels objectAtIndex:i];

    [contentView addSubview:panel];

    // add constraints to position each panel
}
```

these are run on a separate thread which is what I believe the issue is. The UI can only be updated on the main thread.

I tried adding:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [contentView addSubview:panel];
});
```

But that raises errors for the constraints (the constraints don't have reference to it since its in a different thread).

If I run `createPanels` on the main thread, the panels will display but it also locks up the UI until its complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many panels are you adding that it's overwhelming the main thread? Maybe a UITableView and cell would be better than "panel" views because they are lazy loaded?

Comment: table view would be nice, but they are 2 columns in portrait and 3 columns in landscape. We want to be able to use as much as the screen as we can

Comment: Have you tried adding the constraints inside the same block as `[contentView addSubView:panel]`?

Comment: The constraints are not the issue, they are not being displayed/showed. When i look at the list of panels, their frame show correct points and sizes. They are where they should be in the contentView.

Comment: "they are 2 columns in portrait and 3 columns in landscape" - what about using UICollectionView?  It's more flexible than table view but still gives you all the lazy loading/reuse benefits.

Comment: @jsd: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm testing it out. Running into performance issues from loading the panel on demand with it though, seems my panel isn't very optimal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163693/creating-a-uicollectionviewcell-with-uiimage-and-uilabels-creates-slow-scrolling

Comment: I did end up converting it to UICollectionView instead of my own creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which constraints are violated, but you could also try:

```
[contentView performSelctorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview) withObject:panel waitUntilDone:YES];
```

instead of

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [contentView addSubview:panel];
});
```

Not sure whether this will help.

Comment: No constraints are violated, iOS doesn't try to break any to make the views fit.